# CakePHP2.3: Building complex conditional Model->find() options

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm not savvy with MySQL or databases generally, so here's a model of my data (table{cols}]) in order to make my question coherent:

`Domains{id, name}` *Note: 'domains' here does not refer to web domains*

`Subdomains{id, domain_id, name}`

`Items{id, subdomain_id, name}`

`SubdomainsItems{id, subdomain_id, item_id}` **no domain_id column!**

My `Items Controller` has a function, `fetchWithin($domains, $subdomains)` which, ultimately, should just execute one of two complexish `find()`. It's the complexish I can't get past.

Programmatically I can achieve this, but I'm quite certain the better way is by clever joins and the like. Alas, currently this is approach:

*If `$domains`is empty, do only steps 2&3, otherwise:*

1. `foreach($domains as $d)`: get all the rows of `Subdomains` where `Subdomain.domain_id` = `Domains.id` as `$subdomains`
2. `foreach($subdomains as $s)` : go get all the rows of `SubdomainsItems` where `SubdomainsItems.subdomain_id` = `Subdomains.id` as `$item_ids`
3. `foreach($items_ids as $i)`: get all the rows of `Items` where `Items.id` = `SubdomainsItems`.`items_id`

This works, but I think this is obviating the power of a relational database and I'd like to understand how this *should* be done (ie. according to either Cakephp convention or simply by whatever MySQL statement would achieve this).

Help would be hugely appreciated, I *try* to learn the more complex aspects of SQL but it just goes right over my head. :S

Comment: your db structure sound a bit weird - why isn't it as simple as `SELECT * FROM items where domain = "example.com" and subdomain in ("list", "of", "subdomains")` (or similar)? I recommend forgetting about Cake until you determine the query you want to execute.

Comment: Ahh, my post, I'm realizing (and will fix) is ambiguous; `items` doesn't have a `domain` column (in this case, domain isn't referring to a web domain but rather a domain within academic study). `domain` is an optional and very broad constraint for selecting `items`. So I'm pretty sure I need to define two find() conditions, one that will get `items` given `subdomains` and another that will get `subdomains` given `domains` and use the result to get `items`. I just don't know the syntax/understand the underlying logic to create those find() calls

Comment: That helps understand your problem - know that _adding_ `domain_id` to your `subdomain_items` table will simplify certain queries (like - find all items for this domain).

Comment: Interesting... I'd never thought of that. Thank you for the tip. I don't suppose you know if Cake will have any problem with that, or if there's anything outside of the most vanilla Cake usage one would need to implement/know of to build a model of such a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Understanding the necessary query

With the structure described in the question the kind of query necessary is of the form:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    items
LEFT JOIN
    subdomains ON (
        items.subdomain_id = subdomains.id
    )
LEFT JOIN
    domains ON (
        subdomains.domain_id = domains.id
    )
WHERE
    domains.name = "foo"
    AND
    subdomains.name IN ('some', 'list', 'of', 'subdomains');
```

Compared to the logic in the question this joins all three tables together and permits finding all items by domain name, or subdomain name (or any other criteria involving any or all three tables); Generally speaking if you want to find data in a db and use more than one query to get it - there's a more efficient way to do it.

### Implementing the find call

There are a number of ways of creating such a query with Cake. The simplest, probably, is to use [the join key](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) and just specify the joins explicitly:

```
function fetchWithin($domains = null, $subdomains = null) {
    $params = array(
        'joins' =>  array(
            array('table' => 'subdomains',
                'alias' => 'Subdomain',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Subdomain.id = Item.subdomain_id',
                )
            ),
            array('table' => 'domains',
                'alias' => 'Domain',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Domain.id = Subdomain.domain_id',
                )
            )
        )
    );

    if ($domains) { // single value or an array
        $params['conditions']['Domain.name'] = $domains;
    }

    if ($subdomains) { // single value or an array
        $params['conditions']['Subdomain.name'] = $subdomains;
    }

    return $this->find('all', $params);
}
```

Comment: Wow guy, thank you so, so much ah ha. I've spent all morning reading a MySQL book and was slowly approaching the above solution, this is big help and quite an effort on your part. Three cheers for being a great netizen.

Comment: I still recommend adding domain_id to your items table - there would be no complexity if that were the case. You could use a before save function to ensure the field is set correctly on insert/update.